# Python nested class design with mock autospec

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm looking at a class hierarchy like this:

```
class LevelOne(object):
    def __init__(self,level_two_inst):
        self.level_two_inst = level_two_inst
        self.data = self.compute_sth(level_two_inst)

class LevelTwo(object):
    def __init__(self,level_three_inst):
        self.level_three_inst = level_three_inst
        self.data = self.compute_sth(level_three_inst)
```

I would like to unit test `LevelOne`. Since the computing step is rather lengthy for each level, I would like to mock `LevelTwo`, using [autospec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing). I would also like to use `spec_st=True` to make sure the attribute data is a valid attribute of `LevelTwo`.

However, to instantiate `LevelOne` for testing, I would need to mock `LevelTwo`, `LevelThree` and so on.

My current work around is to do this:

```
class LevelOne(object):
    def __init__(self,level_two_inst=None):
        if level_two_inst is None:
            self.data = None
            return
        self.level_two_inst = level_two_inst
        self.data = self.compute_sth(level_two_inst)
```

Now I can set the `data` attribute as I wish when running my test for `LevelOne`. However, I don't like `level_two_inst` to be an optional attribute, as it really is necessary.

I'm new to testing, especially using mocks. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to use a combination of [side_effect and return_value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide) on a mocked `LevelTwo` instance (that does not rely on `LevelThree`) and pass that into the constructor for `LevelOne` so that `self.compute_sth(level_two_inst)` will set the `data` correctly.

Comment: "However, to use autospec like this I need to instantiate LevelOne...". You mean LevelTwo, right? Could you provide some code from your test and comment where is the problem exactly?

Comment: I edited the sentence to make it more clear. Let's say I want to instantiate `LevelTwo` to pass it to my class under test. Then I will need an instance of `LevelThree` etc. I guess one way out, would be to mock out the __init__ method on `LevelTwo` and set `data` to some test value. But then I cannot use `spec_st=True` as `data` will not be defined.